# SQL insert if certain name not in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I want to insert records into a table:

| UserType | UserName | Valid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | Name1 | True |

Currently I am using the following sql code:

```
insert into table_name
select 'certain type', 'a user''s name', 1
```

but if `a user's name` has been recorded in the table, that will cause duplicated names in `UserName` column.

In other words, I want to insert a row of record if `a user's name` does not show up in the `UerName` column. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: This is your user table it seems, so you want the names to be unique in the table. Add a unique constraint or even make the name the table's primary key.

Comment: @D-Shih MS SQL Server

Comment: @ThorstenKettner could you give me some sample codes ?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (username);` or `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT pk_table_name PRIMARY KEY (username);` or `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT uk_table_name UNIQUE (username);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you want to enforce unique values within column in a table.

In that case you can either use [unique](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) constraint on a column, or if that's MSSQL (T-SQL) you can do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM table_name WHERE column_name='a user''s name') BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table_name (UserType, UserName, VALID) VALUES ('certain type', 'a user''s name', 1)
END
```

Comment: yes, it is MSSQL and thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `not exists` condition:

```
insert into t(usertype, username, valid)
select *
from (values
    ('type1', 'name1', 1),
    ('type2', 'name2', 2)
) as to_insert(usertype, username, valid)
where not exists (
    select 1
    from t
    where t.username = to_insert.username
)
```